# Is there a way to show grib2 or netcdf data on shapefiles using web interface?

Tags: netcdf, grib, mercator, mapshaper

I want to show some weather data on a given shapefile. I was checking if it's possible using mapshaper or web mercator but didn't find a suitable procedure.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've done this once in R, I'm not sure if this is possible to do without rolling up your sleeves and writing a R or python script.

Comment: Use for this purpose ArcGIS.